# submit form with jquery and icheck plugin

Tags: jquery, form-submit, icheck

can some body tell me how to get the form submittet on change using the icheck plugin?
here is the link to the plugin:
http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ifchecked` method and `forms['name'].submit();`.